# Does bug IVY-1576 still exist in 2.5.2?

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I came across this issue when I tried to add org.tensorflow:tensorflow-core-platform-gpu:0.5.0 through `spark-submit --packages`.
I found out that ivy resolves and fetches all jars with classifiers, but skips the ones without.

The way to reproduce it:

```bash
java -jar apache-ivy-2.5.2/ivy-2.5.2.jar \
    -dependency "org.tensorflow" "tensorflow-core-platform-gpu" "0.5.0" \
    -retrieve "ivy/\[organization\]\_\[artifact\]-\[revision\](-\[classifier\]).\[ext\]" \
    -confs "runtime" \
    -debug
```

The files in ivy folder are:

```
com.google.protobuf_protobuf-java-3.19.4.jar
org.bytedeco_javacpp-1.5.8-windows-x86_64.jar
org.bytedeco_javacpp-1.5.8-linux-x86_64.jar
org.tensorflow_tensorflow-core-api-0.5.0-linux-x86_64-gpu.jar
org.tensorflow_tensorflow-core-api-0.5.0-windows-x86_64-gpu.jar
org.tensorflow_ndarray-0.4.0.jar
```

Both `org.bytedeco_javacpp-1.5.8.jar` and `org.tensorflow_tensorflow-core-api-0.5.0.jar` are missing.

[pom file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-core-platform-gpu/0.5.0/tensorflow-core-platform-gpu-0.5.0.pom)

I also sent an email to dev@ant.apache.org but got no response.